# Replace image url's in WordPress export file

Tags: php, jquery, html, regex, wordpress

Is there an easy way I can replace all the image urls in a WordPress export file with a different url which I can use to replace all the images with a placeholder image.

Currently in the xml file the paths to the images are as follows :

```
<guid isPermaLink="false">http://demo.mydomain.com/theme/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/IMAGE_161008_159-1500x1200.jpg</guid>
```

I need to change all the urls to something like this instead :

```
http://mytheme.com/placeholder-image.jpg
```

Any ideas how ?

ideally id like to do it using regex search replace in Atom

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
https*:\/\/.+(jpg|png|jpeg)[^<\]\]>]*
```

Replace:

```
http://mytheme.com/placeholder-image.jpg
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say I need to do it in Atom using regex search and replace

Comment: Thanks but wouldnt that change all urls and not just the ones that are images ?

Comment: So just images? Which extensions though?

Comment: just jpg, jpeg, and png I guess

Comment: Updated the regex

Comment: Thankyou. When i search for that in the file it finds results like this which seems to have extra characters on the end i dont want to replace, any ideas ? http://demo.mydomain.com/theme/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/slide1.jpg]]>

Comment: Thanks. That works but i think I need to find a new method as its not importing the images, but thanks anyway.